# How to print the first date entry above a string in Python and Flask?

Tags: python, regex, list, file

I have a list in a text file that looks like this:

```
2019-11-11 13:44:58.879616
ADDED ON THURSDAY NIGHT
185.236.11.8
195.54.161.122
167.86.99.201
147.135.222.214
2019-11-12 13:44:58.879616
ADDED ON FRIDAY NIGHT
185.236.11.8
195.54.161.122
167.86.99.201
147.135.222.214
```

The list is simply the date that IPs were added on, the description, and the list of IPs. This list keeps appending from another source. I want to use python to search this text file for a specific IP (ex. 167.86.99.201) and then read the first date entry and description above it with the list of IPs that were added with that IP to a variable so I can use it with Flask in an HTML output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this - assuming that your text file is not encoded in any way.  You can detect which lines are dates and which ones are ip addresses and make a dictionary that is easy to search.

```
import re
from dateutil import parser

ipAddress = "192.168.1.255"
#first build a dictionary which you can easily search
ipChk = re.compile(r'^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$')
searchSet = {}
for each in open("file.txt", "r"):
    try:
        date = parser(each)
        pDate = date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        searchSet[pDate] = []
    except:
        if ipChk.match(each):
            searchSet[pDate].append(each)


for k, v in searchSet.items()
    if ipAddress in v:
        print("Date: %s, IP: %s" % (k, v))
```

If your text file is really large, you can do the inverse (make your IP address the key and an array of dates for the value) for easier searching.  you'll need to add an extra line so that you don't overwrite your IP dict key for each entry.